# Jetty Request handling

Tags: websocket, jetty, cometd, jetty-9

I am running websockets on jetty 9.2.7 with cometd 3. The average number of requests we get per minute is about 3000. The server stops accepting requests at 6000 requests. Once it reaches 6000 requests per minute, it slows down for a while, stops accepting new requests, opens way too many files than it usually does and eventually dies. It all takes about 3 - 4 mins for the server to stop from the moment it reaches 6000 requests.

The server is running on m3.large amazon instance. ( 7.5 GB RAM and 2 CPUS, High Frequency Intel Xeon E5-2670 v2 (Ivy Bridge) Processors*
SSD-based instance storage for fast I/O performance
Balance of compute, memory, and network resources )

I have 1500 max threads configured on the jetty.xml and 15 acceptors. ( I read acceptors should be <= the number of CPUS. But it did not harm to have many acceptors)

Any insight would be helpful.
Thanks!

EDIT:

Hi, Thank you for getting back to me. I left the acceptors to default now. Here is a snapshot of the CPU usage, Memory usage, no. of requests we got and the files open on the server.
If you notice the requests between 10:51:01 to 10:53:01, the requests went up by about 5000. That is because the comet connections turn to polling. All our clients start to poll instead of holing the connection alive.

The files are configured to  65535.

I have some requests that are taking 18 seconds to complete. We get about 20,000 of them a day. 
I have some requests that take 5 seconds to complete and I get about 200,000 of such requests a day.

Could the requests with high latency be causing the problem?

[image]

Edit : 20/02/2015:

I think I am lost and not sure how to describe the problem.

I looked at the post you shared (http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_concepts_threading ? ) and I implemented the same in all the Listeners. It seemed to have soothed the problem.

However, What I find now in the server thread dump is hundreds of the following logs. Apart from that, some of our code has some Synchronized methods and all those methods go to Blocked state at one point that is effecting the application behavior.

Everytime the server is dead, when I looked at the server dump, there are a bunch of Idle threads and blocked threads in the code. All the times, the entire thread dump has only ONE of those synchronized methods in blocked state. Looks like All these IDLE threads are waiting for the Blocked Synchronized thread to get into runnable state and complete executing?

|   +- 158 qtp364089744-158 TIMED_WAITING IDLE

|   +- 159 qtp364089744-159 TIMED_WAITING IDLE

|   +- 160 qtp364089744-160 TIMED_WAITING IDLE

|   +- 162 qtp364089744-162 TIMED_WAITING IDLE

Now, What I am confused about is, before I see all these IDLE threads in the dump, I see a huge amount of socket timeout exceptions!  How do I interpret the problem? The Socket timeouts are because of the IDLE Threads? Or IDLE threads are beacuse of Socket timeouts?

This is happening on our production server and I am confused at this cross roads! Any suggestion would be greatly helpful.

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout on Read

at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onReadTimeout(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:526)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractConnection.java:173)

at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:496)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:582)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thank you!

Comment: what's average time of processing a single request? I hope its not 250 ms?

Comment: Some take few milli seconds and Some requests take more than 30 secs!!

Comment: Can we configure the response time in the jetty logs so I can find the average?

Comment: Well, I got the answer myself. setLogLatency(true)

Comment: We benchmarked CometD on Amazon nodes at way beyond 100k requests/s, so if 6k is enough to put you in troubles, it smells of some misconfiguration. In particular, the default OS configuration for number of open files and number of child processed is typically too small, and you should not configure 15 acceptors - leave that at default. I suggest you join the CometD mailing list (http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_contribute_mailing_lists) and detail your setup there, since there is too little information here to help you out.